# Javascript remove double quotes from string having forward slash

Tags: javascript, mongodb

**What I have :** I have following string `"/.\*n.*/"`

**What I want :** I want to remove double quotes from above string which will look like `/.\*n.*/`

**What I tried :**

```
var filter = "/.\*n.*/";

var modifiedFilter = filter.replace(/"/g, "");
```

Somehow this code is not working. When I look at modifiedFilter in debug mode, It still shows string with double quotes `"/.\*n.*/"`.
Is it because its a string variable and debug value shows string in double quotes?

But if it is the case, then I am passing this variable to mongodb query and there query is not working due to double quotes.

What am I missing?

Comment: _"then I am passing this variable to mongodb query and there query is not working due to double quotes"_ - Then your query is the problem.

Comment: The double quotes are not really there. They are just signifying "this is a string".

Comment: @Andreas, I tried running query in Robo3T and there it seems to be working. But I will check again. Thanks for pointer.

Comment: Regex out the quotes if they do exist, str = str.replace(/\"/g, ""); in general quotes in logs are wrapped with quotes when they are strings like others have mentioned

Comment: What error do you get from mongodb or is it just that you do not get the desired result?

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to remove `"` from `"/.\*n.*/";` in your case as it is required to create strings. It is only possible if `"/.\*n.*/";` denotes the actual value of the string and in that case assignment should look like `var filter = '"/.\*n.*/"'`, and this problem will have sense for the answerers.

Just use `var modifiedFilter = filter.replace(/\"/g, "")`.

First have a look at the below statements executed on Node REPL.

```
> s = "/.\*n.*/"
'/.*n.*/'
>
> s.replace(/'/g, '')
'/.*n.*/'
>
> s = "'/.\*n.*/'"
'\'/.*n.*/\''
>
> s.replace(/'/g, '')
'/.*n.*/'
>
```

Now have a look at the below code.

```
var s = '"/.\*n.*/"'
var output = s.replace(/\"/g, "")
console.log(s) // "/.*n.*/" 
console.log(output) // /.*n.*/
```

Comment: There are no quotes in the input data (`var filter = "/.\*n.*/";`). Adding them to justify your answer doesn't make it better.

Comment: That is correct **@Andreas**, I just suggested as it is impossible to remove `"` from the given string as it is required to create strings so I thought mistakenly the questioner forgot. So I added but did not comment as already numerous comments are there related to that. I have updated my answer with clarifications. Please have a look and thank you for reminding.

Comment: @hygull: this post answers the question as stated, which is not very useful. __Of course__, there are no removable quotes there. Although OP _did_ say "remove quotes", from their example it's quite obvious that what he actually wants is to transform this string into a regex. Why he didn't just say so, I can't tell. Maybe he isn't aware of the concept of regex. Or existence of types other than strings. Or how programming languages work in general (difference between literals and their values).

Comment: @hygull JFYI, don't decorate mentions with bold. They stop working. Use regular autocompletion, which open when you start typing a name after `@`.

Comment: Okay Thanks @Sergio.

Answer (score -1):

```js
// To have quotes in your string, assign it like following:
var filter = '"/.\*n.*/"';
// Your code to remove the quotes is correct.
var modifiedFilter = filter.replace(/"/g, "");
// Verify that the code worked
console.log(filter, modifiedFilter)
```

Comment: _"I want to **remove** double quotes..."_ (that aren't there in the first place)

Comment: downvoted, why? Give me a reason so that we can discuss :)

Comment: @LuckySoni: see first comment.

Comment: Yes, this answer aims to tell exactly that.

Comment: @LuckySoni: no, you didn't understand the question. There are no quotes there. Nothing to remove with a replace.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I get that. if I didn't understand that there are no quotes, why would i show a way to add them :)

Comment: @LuckySoni: indeed, that is beyond my understanding (adding quotes so you can remove them). In the meanwhile, the question is about something else entirely.

Comment: I answered the exact question that was asked. Who knows where the actual data with quotes is coming from? Maybe the source of data actually sends the data with double quotes but the asker is trying to replicate that data in JS incorreclty. And because he made an incorrect assignment statement, he thinks his code is not working. Who knows?

Comment: @LuckySoni: "I answered the exact question" - far from it. Look at your string and their string. It's two different strings. You _made up_ a question and answered it.

Comment: You're making assumptions which are contrary to the given example. The input is a simple string without any quotes in it but your input data has...

Comment: i think your arguments make sense. My approach to think about it was a bit off. 

Answer (score -2):

Your problem here is either with the query, or with attempting to treat a string primitive directly as a regular expression. Instead of trying to remove the (non-existent) speech marks, instead use the `RegExp` constructor to convert it into a regular expression.

```
var filter = "/.\*n.*/";
var modifiedFilter = new RegExp(filter).slice(1, -1);
```

The string needs to be sliced because the `RegExp` constructor accepts a regular expression without `//` marks.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time and answering the question. I will try and let you know if your answer works. Cheers!!

Comment: @PeterB If it works, could you click the tick? (This goes for whichever answer works, but you can only pick one.) It'll help to counteract the downvotes that somebody _keeps giving_.

Comment: You almost got it right. If you're passing the string to regexp constructor, strip the surrounding slashes. They're part of regex literal syntax. If you're passing them along, that would make a quite different expression.

Comment: Oh, ok. I keep forgetting the idiosyncrasies of JavaScript.